# Can a Java constructor promote a type?

Tags: java, types, constructor, primitive

If I understand correctly, Java methods can promote types: for example, if a method's parameters are two ints, two byte variables can be passed to the invocation, and they will be promoted to ints. Is this true of constructors? Could two byte variables be passed to a constructor whose parameters are two ints?

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  I found that out by opening an IDE, typing it in, and running it.  Not that hard.

Comment: Flipping this on its head: why *couldn't* a ctor act roughly the same as a method in this regard? What benefit would there be to having different semantics?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass byte arguments to integer parameters in constructor.
What happens there is called [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html)